# Respond to key event when the application is out of focus(inactive)

Tags: java, events, keyboard, java-native-interface, lost-focus

I want to capture key event at all time, even when my application is not in focus. For instance, My application should detect `Ctrl+SPACE` key combination while the focus is with other application, and should respond accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is OS Specific, out of the JVM scope.

Here are two good open source Java libraries for achieving what you want:

- [JIntellitype](http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/) - Windows
- [JXGrabKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/) - X11

Both are JNI Wrappers.

Comment: I'm glad to be of service. ;)

Comment: Sorry to post in such an ancient question, but is there a multiplatform language where I can develop a program that checks keys even while inactive?

Comment: Use C / C++ to work with your desktop environment / SO APIs and intercept key bindings. Java is also a good choice because of JNI. .NET languages may be able to do it directly on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

not possible with pure Java, when applications lost `Focus`, then `Focus Subsystem` is managed by `Native OS`, there exist some way how to do by unsing `JNI`, notice `Key ShoutCuts` should be `Anti_Virus` sensitive

Comment: Oh! I almost forgot to mention, I am using JNA with java, can I use JNA to do the same. If so, Could you please help on that? I have seen `WordWeb` offline dictionary application, which responds to `Ctrl+Alt+W` key combination. It is not posing threat to Antivirus. Anyhow threat is trivial thing to consider. Thanks a lot.